# Why download button on Python website doesn't work

Tags: python, button, flask

I have Flask website in which I want to add download button which downloads .csv file with scraped data.

In my html file I have this code:

```
<a href="cms_scrape.csv" ><button>Download!</button></a>
```

And only output I get is error: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

File is in its proper folder.

My folder structure:

```
└───Project
│   cms_scrape.csv
│
└───templates

        index.html
```

Comment: What is "its proper folder"? How are you serving that folder with your flask website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to specify some sort of route on the backend of your site.

For instance, somewhere in your flask site, you probably have a route `@app.route('/')` for your index.  You will need a similar route for your file.  That route will go out onto your file system and return the file itself.

```
@app.route('/csv_file')
def csv_file():
    return flask.send_file('path/to/file/cms_scrape.csv',
                           attachment_filename='cms_scrape.csv',
                           as_attachment=True)
```

You will also need to modify your html to access a route and not the file name directly (unless you create your routes dynamically, of course):

```
<a href="/csv_file" ><button>Download!</button></a>
```

Comment: No problem. Just be aware that there may be security implications if you make the url generic.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure about this but I think the  tag has a download attribute you can use. Then you don't need the button.

Usage:

```
<a href="/path/to/file" download>
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can make links to files with the

```
{{ url_for('static', filename='filename.foo') }}
```

function inside your template. You have to store the file in a folder named 'static' which should be located in the directory where the main scipt is.

The link in your template should look like this:

```
<a href=" {{ url_for('static', filename='cms_scrape.csv') }} " download>Download!</a>
```